# JS code does not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have the following code

```
$('.checkbox.radio-info input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 1)
    {
        $(".checkbox.radio-info input[type='checkbox'").prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

This works as expected on desktop, however, on my iPhone (iOS 9, Chrome) it doesn't work. It does not uncheck the checkbox when I check another one.

Is there anything in this code that could be device related?

Comment: Have you imported jQuery properly?

Comment: Yes - I am using quite a lot jQuery on my website, and the rest is working properly on my phone.

Comment: try with $().click() event instead of $().change()

Comment: How can I check console errors on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing a "]" in the line: 
`$(".checkbox.radio-info input[type='checkbox'").attr('checked', false);`

Maybe your desktop browser is more forgiving?

If this doesn't help, please share your HTML as well.

Comment: It was a 'ohhh' moment for me, but unfortunately it doesn't solve it. Wel seen though ;-)

Comment: This was the problem. I failed uploading the file, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try attr instead of prop in your code.

```
$('.checkbox.radio-info input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
if ($(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 1)
{
    $(".checkbox.radio-info input[type='checkbox'").attr('checked', false);
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
}});
```

Comment: it depends on jQuery version